# Absolute difference in Minimization in NSP

Tags: python, optimization, constraint-programming, or-tools

I'm new to both Python and constraint programming, I'm sure there's something really simple/stupid that's throwing an error.

I'm trying to minimize the surplus of items relative to a forecast (trying to match the forecast as close as possible).  To do this, it seems like looking at the **absolute difference** for each day and interval would be a good start.  The *absolute* part is where I'm having difficulty.

For background:

- `items` is a `BoolVar` for each item, day, and timeblock
- `forecast` is an array for each day and timeblock

My minimization function is as follows:

```
model.Minimize(sum(abs(sum(items[(i, d, t)] for i in all_items) - forecast[d][t]) for d in all_days for t in all_timeblocks))
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): '_SumArray'
```

Any help/input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abs, min, and max are python constructs that are not understood by the solver.

You need to use

```
model.AddAbsEquality(target_var, [x1, .. xn])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I was able to correctly minimize my surplus using this.  Also, I'd like to thank you in general.  At least 60%-70% of the questions I search for are either answered by you, or have helpful feedback from you.